# Ec2 instances Public IP - Where it is assigned?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am still learning AWS so please bear with me. I tried searching google but couldnt get any precise answer to my question. I am a CCIE myself so networking is not new to me.

When we create new EC2 instance in default VPC every instance gets a Public IP and Private IP. Private IP is assigned to the ENI. Perfect. Where is the public ip assigned? how its done? i think it should be NAT behind the scenes right? or else how can you assign a Public IP without actually assigning it somewhere.

Please confirm my doubt

I tried to find the answer in aws documentation but couldnt find it

Comment: Yes it is a NAT behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behind the scenes, the public ip is VIP that is mapped to the private ip address using static nat.

Comment: Thank you for clearing my doubt. Just out of curiosity, is this mentioned anywhere in aws documentation?

Comment: I can't seem to find anything related to this in aws documentation, I will try later. To complete my answer: the public ip address is reserved from aws owned public ip addresses, but you can also bring your own public cidr to your aws account. When you associate the public ip address/EIP to an instance/eni, the internet gateway on the VPC automatically performs a one to one nat mapping between this public ip and the eni/instance private one.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon has it's own pool of public ip addresses, which gets assigned to your instances based on where you deployed them.

> A public IP address is assigned to your instance from Amazon's pool of public IPv4 addresses, and is not associated with your AWS account. When a public IP address is disassociated from your instance, it is released back into the public IPv4 address pool, and you cannot reuse it.

See here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html

I'm not sure if you're looking for a more in-depth answer.

But something to be aware of, is that AWS will start charging you for all active and waiting public ip addresses, due to the shortage.

See announcement: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-public-ipv4-address-charge-public-ip-insights/